# Modeling missing arguments in a Scenario Outline Examples section

Tags: python, gherkin

Assume the following:

```
Scenario Outline: various bits
    When a thing named "bog standard" is created with "<name>", "<path>", and "<type>"
    Then the system should respond with <response>
  Examples:
    | name | path           | type | response |
    |      |                |      | 400      |
```

The python @When(u'a thing named...") annotated method is not invoked for this input. Apparently the parameters have to have a least one non-space character. I get a NotImplementedException for any test which includes a missing value.

How can I make this work? I want to test the missing values. I would like either None or "" passed to the step method.

Also, if I wanted leading spaces on an argument, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Gherkin is pretty "opinionated" when it comes to parsing the example tables.

The simplest way to get what you're asking for is to use a placeholder value, such as "none" or "n/a", and check for the placeholder in your step definition.  You can use comments to forewarn the reader about the placeholder value. 
 Remember that the Gherkin is primarily intended to be human readable/editable.

Regarding leading spaces, there is currently no easy way to get them in an example table. There is an [issue](https://github.com/cucumber-attic/gherkin/issues/232) raised in the Gherkin project to address this.

Some alternatives:

- use a placeholder, e.g. tilde or period to represent the leading space

`Examples:
    | name                        | response |
    | ...has three leading spaces | 100      |`

- put the string as a quote

`When the user inputs " string with one leading space" in the path`

- use doc strings to hold strings with leading spaces or even multi-line strings:

`When the user inputs
         """
            This one has three leading spaces
         """`